# Spring Boot with Liberty Profile on Docker

Tags: docker, spring-boot, websphere-liberty

Is there any example of creating Spring Boot application with Liberty Profile which should be deployed on Docker.

I have below requirements.
1.Need to create a Spring Boot application.Executable jar.
2.It should use Liberty Profile as run time server.If possible we need to package server in jar itself.
3.This should be deployed/run in Docker.

Comment: Are you looking for some pointers on getting started or did you run into a specific problem you're not sure how to address?

Comment: @R0MANARMY I am looking to getting started as I am new to docker and Liberty Profile.Using Spring Boot with websphere Application Server 8.5 already.

Comment: Have you already tried [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to deploy on Docker then why do you need an executable JAR? Why not build the Spring Boot app as a WAR and then add it to an image that already has the Liberty runtime?

If you really do need the executable JAR, you can't embed Liberty in a Spring Boot executable JAR but you could create an executable JAR with Liberty and the Spring Boot WAR: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_setup_jarserver.html

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to deploy applications on docker websphere-liberty, you can use "websphere-liberty:latest" docker image available on docker hub and follow the instraictions.

See more information below.
https://hub.docker.com/r/library/websphere-liberty/